Referencing endpoints in module of gradle composite build
I have a monolith that exposes a set of APIs. It uses Gradle and has no OpenAPI spec for the APIs, it actually uses Swagger UI to generate the definition on the fly. I am adding a module to the monolith, that needs to expose two more endpoints. This time I built a YAML spec for the API and used OpenAPI generator to generate POJOs.
The module has its own Gradle files, and I include the module's classes in the monolith using includeBuild 'Module-A' in the monolith's settings.gradle.
Both module and monolith build and run well, and I would expect the endpoints to be visible in the big OpenAPI specification generated on the fly and accessible when I run the module independently.
What in reality happens is that I cannot see in the OpenAPI spec generated on the fly nor access the endpoints from the monolith , nor can I access them in Postman when I run the module as an independent application.
Do I need to add some context-path to the call path? How do I make the endpoints in the module accessible in a composite Gradle build? Am I doing anything wrong, or not doing something I should?
Thank you in advance for any help.
